# USB 2.0 port not working

Tags: usb, 15.04, external-hdd, troubleshooting

And that goes for every of mine External HDDs, USB 3.0 ports are working fine. When I connect mouse receiver in it (2.0), it's working fine.

**lsusb output when connected to usb 2.0**:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0139 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5139 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b3d8 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**lsusb output when connected to usb 3.0 no. 1**:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0139 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5139 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b3d8 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 015: ID 152d:2329 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp. JM20329 SATA Bridge
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**lsusb output when connected to usb 3.0 no. 2**:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0139 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5139 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b3d8 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 016: ID 152d:2329 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp. JM20329 SATA Bridge
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

---

**dmesg | grep USB when connected to 3.0**:

```
[68215.576480] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[68215.713288] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=2329
[68215.713292] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
[68215.713294] usb 1-2: Product: USB to ATA/ATAPI bridge
[68215.713871] usb-storage 1-2:1.0:USB Mass Storage device detected
```

**dmesg | grep USB when connected to 2.0**:

just one more line about disconnection...
`[68501.356512] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 16` which is about disconnecting HDD from the USB 2.0 port.

---

**ls /dev/ | grep sd** (with device disconnected)

```
sda
sda1
sdb
sdb1
```

**ls /dev/ | grep sd** (after connecting)

```
sda
sda1
sdb
sdb1
```

---

**sudo fdisk -l | grep /dev/sd (USB 2.0)**

```
Disk /dev/sda: 232,9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
/dev/sda1  *     2048 488396579 488394532 232,9G 83 Linux
Disk /dev/sdb: 22,4 GiB, 24015495168 bytes, 46905264 sectors
/dev/sdb1   2048 46903295 46901248 22,4G Linux swap
```

**sudo fdisk -l | grep /dev/sd (USB 3.0)**

```
Disk /dev/sda: 232,9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
/dev/sda1  *     2048 488396579 488394532 232,9G 83 Linux
Disk /dev/sdb: 22,4 GiB, 24015495168 bytes, 46905264 sectors
/dev/sdb1   2048 46903295 46901248 22,4G Linux swap
Disk /dev/sdc: 931,5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
/dev/sdc1        2048 1953521663 1953519616 931,5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

---

**sudo udevadm monitor** in USB 2.0

gives no output, but power is in it, because I can charge phone via it

**EDIT:**

*On Linux Mint 17.2  (the same machine) all of USB ports are working! Is there any way to "port" those settings ,or whatever is affecting it, to Ubuntu?*

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple probable causes for this behaviour.
What first comes to mind is that the USB current exceeds it's maximum. This causes the USB controller to reset and so the drive doesn't work. The mouse receiver uses less power so it works. You probably need to connect the drive using a powered USB hub, or connect it to the USB 3.0 hub.

A less likely cause is that this particular drive causes the USB hub to reset on ATA probing (not power related). There have been bug reports about this some time ago. But since you describe that the drive works on another USB port I don't think this scenario is very likely in your situation.

Comment: Funny thing is, that it was working on Windows, but I'm not going back to it... that's why I'm trying to make it work. Beside HDDs I've tried USB pen drives with the same results (not connecting).